# Javascript Notification Pop-up?

Tags: javascript

Looking for the best approach to perform a javascript notification pop-up if amount in field A is edited to a smaller amount that what is found in field B?

We aren't using any js frameworks but that option isn't ruled out.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem. Could you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend jQuery then you could do:

```
   <input id='fld1' type=text value=5>
   <div id="label1" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>
   <input id='fld2' type=text value=5>
```

and in your script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fld1').change(function(){
                if($(this).val()>$('#fld2').val()){
                  //display it on the form
                  $('#label1').append('Fld 1 cannot be bigger than fld2!').show();
                  //or alert it to the user using alert();
                   alert('Fld 1 cannot be bigger than fld2!');
                }
            })
        });
```

see http://api.fatherstorm.com/test/4168233.php

Comment: This works great, thanks!
How would I go about hiding the <div id="label"> and have it only show when the function is EQ true?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the `alert` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alert` function

```
if(valueOfFieldA < valueOfFieldB)
{
    alert('please enter amount greater than Field B');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jNASS/) is what you were looking for.

Code rewritten here for your convenience

**HTML**

```
<label>A</label><input type="text" id="input1" onblur="checkBValue()"/><br/>
<label>B</label><input type="text" id="input2"/>
```

**JS**

```
function checkBValue(){

    var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value);
    var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value);
    if (a<b && !isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)) alert("A="+a+ " is less than B="+b);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply, you can create a js function and call it with `onchange` event of the A input,
so you can specify your special way to notify user ;)

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug, but here's a library I've written to handle notifications very easily: http://shaundon.github.io/simple-notifications/